# extjs grid column renderer not calling

Tags: extjs, grid, renderer

cannot find answer (

```
Ext.define('Cabinet.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
...
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        docked: 'top',
        title: 'Sliding Menu',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                id: 'listButton',
                iconCls: 'x-fa fa-bars',//list  //x-fa fa-mortar-board
                ui: 'plain',

                listeners : {
                tap: 'OnToggle' 
                }       
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        xtype: 'container',
        flex: 1,
        itemId: 'contentPanel',
                reference: 'mainCardPanel',     
                scrollable: 'y',
                    layoutConfig:{layoutOnCardChange:true},
                    layout: {
                        type: 'card',
                        anchor: '100%'
                    }       
    }
],
,
initialize: function(){
        Ext.Viewport.setMenu(this.createMenu(),{
            side: 'left',
            reveal: true
        });
        this.callParent();
    },

    createMenu: function(){
        var menu = Ext.create('Ext.Menu', {
            width: 250,
            defaultListenerScope: true,
            scrollable: 'vertical',
            controller: 'main',
    ViewModel :
    {

    },          

    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'asd',
        viewName: 'acadPerf',
        controller: 'main',
        listeners : {
        tap: function ()
        {
            if (Ext.Viewport.down('#contentPanel').getActiveItem() != 0) {
Ext.Viewport.down('#contentPanel').getActiveItem().destroy();
                        }
                        newView = Ext.create({xtype: this.viewName});
                        Ext.suspendLayouts();
                        Ext.Viewport.down('#contentPanel').setActiveItem(newView);
                        Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
                       load store


Ext.define('Cabinet.view.charts.acadPerf', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype: 'acadPerf',

    viewModel: {
     //   type: 'charts'
    },

    layout: 'fit', //responsivecolumn 

    defaults: {
        defaults: {
            animation : !Ext.isIE9m && Ext.os.is.Desktop
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        render: function () {
            this.down('grid').getStore().reload();
        }
    },

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            cls: 'faq-left-sidebar shadow',
            header: false,
            ui: 'light',
            layout: 'fit', 
            responsiveConfig: {
                'width < 1000': {
                    width: 0,
                    visible: false
                },
                'width >= 1000 && width < 1600': {
                    width: 230,
                    visible: true
                },
                'width >= 1600': {
                    width: 300,
                    visible: true
                }
            },
            items: [
            { 
                xtype:'grid',
                reference: 'mainCardPanel',     
                store: 'acadPerfStore',

                hideHeaders: true, 
                columns: [
                {
                        text: 'asd',
                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                        flex: 1,
                        dataIndex: 'CONTROL_FORM',
                        cell: {
              encodeHtml: false  
          },
                        renderer: 'renderTitleColumnAcademPerf' 
                },

                ]
        }
            ]
         }
    ],
...
```

when i at first time click to show menu and then tap on first button - all ok.
renderer work. I see all records.

but when i click once again to show menu and click on first button - i see only content of one record from store. but the size of verical scroll of grid is like all records rendered. in html i see only one record.

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you using modern ?

Comment: yes. Modern toolkit. in classic all ok